# Delphi - SQL Server query takes a long time to run

Tags: delphi-xe3

Delhi XE3 Enterprise, SQL Server 2008

When I run the following the query it takes 4 seconds to run in the Delphi program.  When I run it from SQL Server management studio it only takes .5 seconds to run.

```
SELECT
      SUM(ISNULL(soi.ExtendedUnitPrice, 0)) AS TotalExtendedUnitPrice,
      SUM(ISNULL(soi.ExtendedUnitCost, 0))  AS TotalExtendedUnitCost,
      SUM(ISNULL(soi.OriginalTotal, 0))     AS TotalOriginalTotal,
      SUM(ISNULL(soi.LineWeight, 0))        AS TotalLineWeight
FROM SalesOrderItems soi
WHERE (soi.SalesOrderID = :SalesOrderID)
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Delphi. Delphi passes the SQL statement to the server to execute. You should view the execution plan for your SELECT and see what it tells you is affecting performance.

Comment: That is true but it still took 4-5 seconds to run it from Delphi but less than .5 seconds when run on SQL server. Once I added the SalesOrderID field, which is indexed, it ran almost as fast on the workstation as it did on the sql server through SQL Management Studio(?).  I don't know why but adding the indexed foreign key sped it up in Delphi.  I am a SQL Server novice so I guess I should have known to add the indexed field from the beginning.  I assume sql server used the index to speed up the operation(?).

Answer (score 0):

To fix it I added the soi.SalesOrderID to the field list and added a GROUP BY SalesOrderID.  Very quick now.